# How to manage ng-includes in ui-router based project

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

Here's my issue:

My project is mainly contained in `index.html`, with `ui-router` placing the various pages in a `<div ui-view></div>` section.

In one my other pages, let's call it `page1`, I have an `ng-include` to a partial in the same subdirectory. However, when I try to include this partial using

```
<div ng-include="'page1Partial.html'"</div>
```

I get a console error that

```
GET http://localhost/myProj/v3/myproj/app/index/page1Partial.html 404
```

This is obviously because ui-router moved my page into `index.html` and it's looking for the `ng-include` based on that directory.

I really don't want to move the partial to the `index` folder, as that structurally makes no sense my project. I also, don't want to type out a whole hardcoded path to this same directory (which could potentially change in the future). I want to be able to refer to this partial in a relative, simple and safe way.

What is the best way to efficiently and quickly manage this issue?

I've included what my file structure looks like:

```
myproj
|-- app
|    |-- index
|    |     |-- index.html
|    |     |-- index.js
|    |-- page1
|    |     |-- page1.html
|    |     |-- page1.js
|    |     |-- page1Partial.html
|    |-- page2
|-- common
|    |-- resources
|    |     |-- page1resources.js
|    |     |-- page2resources.js
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that `page1.html` is a partial that is included using `ui-router` and never accessed directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is in fact a single-page app (user opens `index.html` and all other pages are dynamically included using `ui-router`), you'd save yourself much hassle by simply putting your single point of access (`index.html`) right in the root folder of your application. All relative paths would then have the root folder as context.

*When creating such single-page applications, it is quite common to create `index.html` automatically during build (see `index` task in `Gruntfile.js` in [ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp)).*

If you cannot (or don't want to) put your `index.html` in your root folder, you could just rewrite URLs (in your server) to make it appear to be there. In Apache, you could use `mod_rewrite` for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /app/index/index.html [QSA]
```

(you'd then access your app at `http://localhost/myproj/`.)

Comment: Implemented. Great tip.